# Scala REPL: LazyLogging Log messages aren't being printed

Tags: scala, playframework

As an example I have

```
package com.myapp

import com.typesafe.scalalogging.LazyLogging

class Foo extends LazyLogging { def foo() = logger.info("hi") }
```

In the REPL when I run

```
val a = new Foo()
a.foo()
```

Nothing prints. Is there a way to have log messages print to the scala repl?

This is a Scala play app where I'm running sbt shell console, my logback.xml looks like this https://pastebin.com/raw/ZMeX6RsD

Comment: Try not using the Async appenders.

Comment: @BobDalgleish I removed them but still nothing prints to the console except the return value of the function (which scala REPL normally does)

Comment: I meant, switch your logging configuration to use STDOUT as the only appender and see if that works.

Comment: You specify `level="WARN"` in logback config, so it will only log errors and warnings, and `info` is disabled.

Comment: @BobDalgleish https://pastebin.com/wY1030cK is the updated logback but it's not working still. I've also changed the root log level to INFO.

Comment: Now you have turned off all logging. You need a reference to STDOUT appender.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/ZMeX6RsD I've added the appender under the root element but it continues not working